# How to turn off the sound of App?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ios-simulator

I want to turn off the sound of a App , because I have a setting of sound , when I switch the sound to off , I want the App not play sound, My app is that:when I load a view and click someplace of it and should play some sound , and now I want to turn off the App sound when users turn off the switch of setting . because I didn't know how the audio play , and it is done by other way , and I want to know how to turn off the App audio by sdk code, How to do, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

```
if (settingToPlaySound) {
 // play your sound here.
}
```

Comment: OK,but My app is that:when I load a view and click someplace of it and should play some sound , and now I want to turn off the App sound when users turn off the switch of setting . because I didn't know how the audio play , and it is done by other way , and I want to know how to turn off the App audio by sdk code, thank you !